# To find all positive integers $n$ such that $a\in \mathbb Z ; n|a(a-1) \implies n|a $ , or $n|a-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How do we find all positive integers $n$ such that $a\in \mathbb Z  ; n|a(a-1) \implies n|a $ , or $n|a-1$ ? The primes certainly satisfy this condition ; what other integers do satisfy this condition ?

Comment: $a$ or $a-1$ prime with $n$ ? I think it means any integer will satisfy that as $a$ is prime with $a-1$ but I might be mistaken (and I'm probably).

Comment: @servabat: $6|3 \times 2 $ but $6$ divides neither $3$ nor $2$ ...

Comment: Then I assume it's wrong with $n=a(a-1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the question as follows.

> Find all (positive) integers $n$ such that ***for all integers $a$***, 
>   $$
> \text{if $n \mid a (a-1)$, then either $n \mid a$ or $n \mid a-1$.}
> $$

Prime powers $n$ clearly satisfy this condition.

So suppose $n = s t$, with $s, t > 1$ coprime. Since $s$ is invertible modulo $t$, clearly there is $k$ such that $t \mid k s + 1$. (Take $-k$ to be the inverse of $s$ modulo $t$.)

Take $a = k s + 1$. Then $n \mid a (a-1)$, as $t$ divides $a$ and $s$ divides $a-1$. But clearly $s$ does not divide $a$ (otherwise it would divide $1$), and $t$ does not divide $a - 1$ (same). So $n$ does not divide $a$ nor $a-1$.

So $n$ must be a prime power.